# cancan on a single page application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, cancan

What is the proper way of checking ability on a single page application (backbone.js)?

E.g. if it was a non-single page application, I could write on the template

```
<% if can :read? @resource %>
  <%= link_to @resource %>
<% end %>
```

But my problem is that I don't have loaded `@resource` yet, when I render a client-side template.

Comment: A good question, but IMO needs to be phrased a little better. Maybe make it more general about how access authorization should be done in Single Page Apps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, access control will be performed on both client and server.  On the server, you can use `authorize!` in your controllers as per normal.  On the client, cancan is not available.

Possible solutions:

1. Render view fragments on the server, where `can?` is available.  I don't think this approach makes much sense with backbone.
2. Expose an API for "cancan queries"
3. Duplicate your ability object on the client

I'm leaning twords exposing an API, but if the network becomes a performance issue I guess you'll have to duplicate your ability object client-side.

This seems like a good example of how client-side apps are more work!